# Не могу зайти в админку WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Я в файле robots.txt для сайта прописываю что запрещаю использование функций с приставкой "wp-" и после этого я не могу зайти в админку сайта что логично, вопрос мне что бы входить в админку нужно каждый раз коректировать robots.txt или есть иной выход. Просто для заказчика это не сильно удобно.

Comment: Во первых внятно описывай что значит "не могу войти". Во вторых:  если проблемы со входом - это явно не роботс. Он физически не может запретить вход и тем более никаких "функции" ([матчасть](http://robotstxt.org/)). И в последних - не пиши в роботс подобной ереси.

Comment: Никакой связи robots и авторизации нет. Вот htaccess может поломать и наложить ограничения.